# Install dial up Conexant modem driver from Dell

Tags: drivers, dell, modem

I want to setup a dial-up connection on another computer (Ubuntu 12.04) without internet access. I have a Conexant modem and I need to download a driver for this. According to [this help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto/Conexant), the drivers provided (for free) by Linuxant are only 14.4 Kbps.

Are there any free drivers by Dell that don't have this speed restriction?

`scanModem` tells me I need to install `hsfmodem-7.80.02.05full_k3.11.0_15_generic_ubuntu_i386.deb.zip` which is downloadable from [Linuxant](http://www.linuxant.com/drivers/hsf/full/downloads.php).

If there's nothing provided by Dell, what other options are there?